# How to integrate Python's GTK with gevent?

Tags: python, winapi, gtk, gevent, gtk3

Gtk is a GUI toolkit with bindings to Python. Gevent is a Python networking library built on top of libevent (libev on newer versions) and greenlets, allowing the usage of network functions inside greenlets without blocking the whole process.

Both Gtk an gevent have blocking main loops that dispatch events. How to integrate their main loops so that I can receive both network events and UI events on my application, without one blocking another?

The naive approach is to register an idle callback on Gtk's main loop, that is called instead whenever there is no Gtk event. In this callback, we yield the greenlet so network events can happen, also giving a small timeout, so the process does not busy waits:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
import gevent

def _idle():
    gevent.sleep(0.1)
    return True

GLib.idle_add(_idle)
```

This approach is far from ideal, because I have a delay of 100 miliseconds between UI events processing, and if I lower the value too much, I waste too much processor busy-waiting.

I want a better approach, where my process is truly asleep while there is no event to process.

PS: I've already found a Linux specific solution (that will probably work under MacOS, too). What I really need now is a working Windows solution.

Comment: Have you tried: https://bitbucket.org/RonnyPfannschmidt/gevent-gtkloop

Comment: Or you can call [`gevent.core.loop`](http://gevent.org/gevent.core.html#gevent.core.loop) instead. This should reduce busy waiting to a minimum.

Answer (score 8):

Given current gevent API, I don't think there is a general solution, but I think there might be specific solutions for each platform.

### Posix solution (tested under Linux)

Since GLib's main loop interface allow us to set the poll function, i.e. the function that takes a set of file descriptor and returns when one of them is ready, we define a poll function that relies on gevent's select to know when the file descriptors are ready.

Gevent does not exposes `poll()` interface, and `select()` interface is a little different, so we have to translate the arguments and the return value when calling `gevent.select.select()`.

What complicate the matters a bit is that GLib does not exposes, through Python's interface, the specific function `g_main_set_poll_func()` that allows the trick. So we have to use the C function directly, for this, the `ctypes` module comes in handy.

```
import ctypes
from gi.repository import GLib
from gevent import select

# Python representation of C struct
class _GPollFD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("fd", ctypes.c_int),
                ("events", ctypes.c_short),
                ("revents", ctypes.c_short)]

# Poll function signature
_poll_func_builder = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(_GPollFD), ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_int)

# Pool function
def _poll(ufds, nfsd, timeout):
    rlist = []
    wlist = []
    xlist = []

    for i in xrange(nfsd):
        wfd = ufds[i]
        if wfd.events & GLib.IOCondition.IN.real:
            rlist.append(wfd.fd)
        if wfd.events & GLib.IOCondition.OUT.real:
            wlist.append(wfd.fd)
        if wfd.events & (GLib.IOCondition.ERR.real | GLib.IOCondition.HUP.real):
            xlist.append(wfd.fd)

    if timeout < 0:
        timeout = None
    else:
        timeout = timeout / 1000.0

    (rlist, wlist, xlist) = select.select(rlist, wlist, xlist, timeout)

    for i in xrange(nfsd):
        wfd = ufds[i]
        wfd.revents = 0
        if wfd.fd in rlist:
            wfd.revents = GLib.IOCondition.IN.real
        if wfd.fd in wlist:
            wfd.revents |= GLib.IOCondition.OUT.real
        if wfd.fd in xlist:
            wfd.revents |= GLib.IOCondition.HUP.real
        ufds[i] = wfd

_poll_func = _poll_func_builder(_poll)

glib = ctypes.CDLL('libglib-2.0.so.0')
glib.g_main_context_set_poll_func(None, _poll_func)
```

I feel that there should be a better solution, because this way we need to know the specific version/name of GLib being used. This could be avoided if GLib exposed `g_main_set_poll_func()` in Python. Also, if `gevent` implements `select()`, it could well implement `poll()`, what would make this solution a lot more simple.

### Windows partial solution (ugly and broken)

Posix solution fails on Windows because `select()` will only work with network sockets, what given Gtk handles aren't. So I thought on using GLib's own `g_poll()` implementation (what is a thin wrapper on Posix, it is a fairly complicated implementation on Windows) in another thread to wait for the UI events, and sync it with gevent's side in the main thread via a TCP socket. This is a very ugly approach, because it requires true threads (apart from greenlets that you probably would be using, if you are using gevent) and plain (non-gevent) sockets on the waiting thread side.

Too bad UI events on Windows are split by threads, so that one thread can not, by default, wait for events on another thread. The message queue on a specific thread is not created until you perform some UI stuff. So I had to create an empty WinAPI message box (`MessageBoxA()`) on the waiting thread (certainly there is a better way to do it), and mangle threads message queues with `AttachThreadInput()` so it can see the events of the main thread. All this via `ctypes`.

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import gevent
from gevent_patcher import orig_socket as socket
from gi.repository import GLib
from threading import Thread

_poll_args = None
_sock = None
_running = True

def _poll_thread(glib, addr, main_tid):
    global _poll_args

    # Needed to create a message queue on this thread:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, ctypes.c_char_p('Ugly hack'),
                                     ctypes.c_char_p('Just click'), 0)

    this_tid = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId())
    w_true = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL(True)
    w_false = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL(False)

    sock = socket()
    sock.connect(addr)
    del addr

    try:
        while _running:
            sock.recv(1)
            ctypes.windll.user32.AttachThreadInput(main_tid, this_tid, w_true)
            glib.g_poll(*_poll_args)
            ctypes.windll.user32.AttachThreadInput(main_tid, this_tid, w_false)
            sock.send('a')
    except IOError:
        pass
    sock.close()

class _GPollFD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("fd", ctypes.c_int),
                ("events", ctypes.c_short),
                ("revents", ctypes.c_short)]

_poll_func_builder = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(_GPollFD), ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_int)
def _poll(*args):
    global _poll_args
    _poll_args = args
    _sock.send('a')
    _sock.recv(1)

_poll_func = _poll_func_builder(_poll)

# Must be called before Gtk.main()
def register_poll():
    global _sock

    sock = gevent.socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
    addr = sock.getsockname()
    sock.listen(1)

    this_tid = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId())
    glib = ctypes.CDLL('libglib-2.0-0.dll')
    Thread(target=_poll_thread, args=(glib, addr, this_tid)).start()
    _sock, _ = sock.accept()
    sock.close()

    glib.g_main_context_set_poll_func(None, _poll_func)

# Must be called after Gtk.main()
def clean_poll():
    global _sock, _running
    _running = False
    _sock.close()
    del _sock
```

This far the application runs and reacts correctly to clicks and other user events, but nothing is drawn inside the windows (I can see the frame and the background buffer pasted into it). Some redraw command may be missing in the mangling of threads and messages queues. It is beyond my knowledge how to fix it. Any help? Any better idea on how to do it?

Comment: Observation: Instead of the socket used for sync both threads in windows impl, you can use a Mutex.

Comment: I believe I tried to use `gevent.coros.Semaphore` for synchronization, because it seemed more appropriated than the ugly TCP socket hack, but it failed with a message saying multiple threads were not supported by gevent. I can't use a non-gevent aware mechanism because it would block gevent's loop from running, pretty much the same thing as if I had just called glib's `g_poll` right there, in the same thread. That is why I resorted to a socket.

Comment: I refered to standard sync objects: [thread.EventObject](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects) as you use real threads; the cores.Semaphore is greenlet implementation, that should be used in greenlet only.

Comment: That is the second case: it would block the main thread instead of allowing gevent to schedule another greenlet.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create a separate thread for handling the Gevent main loop. And you need a mechanism for switching safe from one thread to other.

1. to switch safe from gui thread to Gevent thread (something similar as Stackless already provided: [switching between diff OS threads in Stackless Python](http://www.disinterest.org/resource/stackless/2.6-docs-html/library/stackless/threads.html#channels-are-thread-safe)).
   A solution to switch safe is to use [libev.ev_async](http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html#ev_async__how_to_wake_up_another_event_loop).

Example code:

```
def in_gevent_thread(data_to_send):
  #now you are in gevent thread, so you can use safe greenlet + and network stuff
    ...

def on_button_click():
  #now you are in gui thread
  safe_switch = gevent.core.async(gevent_hub.loop)
  safe_switch.callback = functools.partial(in_gevent_thread, data_to_send)
  safe_switch.send()
```

1. to switch back from gevent thread to gui thread should be easy. Something similiar to WinApi PostThreadMessage should be in gtk, too  ...

Comment: This solution is not acceptable because it would require me for rewrite the rest of the application, and would incur too much synchronization complexity, that is avoided on a cooperative threading system like greenlets, and precisely the point in trying to integrate the main loops.

Comment: I expected that all your logic is in gevent thread, and the gui is in gtk thread (a good architecutre should separe thise 2 concepts); so no thread synchronization is needed in gevent thread, in gui thread too. Only requirement is that for communitcate between gui and logic(gevent) need a async mechanism for thread switching (the ideea is already presented in my answer)

Comment: The isolation of these two concepts in different threads is a "good architecture" just because of the platform limitations that doesn't allow these two to be interchangeably used without the need of synchronization. This limitation is what I am trying to leverage, so to allow seamless integration between those two, raising the abstraction level of their "communication" to simple function calls (what in OO terminology, is message passing between objects). You are simply suggesting for me to rollback to the old, harder and explicit programming model I am trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: I refered to good architecture to have separate layers gui and logic, this doesnt mean that each layer should run in separate thread. So, having this separation, it should be not very difficult to adapt your code for 2 mention threads;

Comment: @lvella You can abstract the communication to simple function calls if you wrap these function calls on a lower level. For example if you have a simple send_message / handle_message protocol you would inject the message sending in the gevent thread by the function above and send the received messages back to the GUI with `gobject.idle_add(message_callback, message)`. If you have a clean architecture this proposal should be very easy to implement.

Comment: This is a graphical summary: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Threaded_loop.png :-)

Comment: Some additional arguments why doing I/O in a separate thread is always a good idea: http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers:design-v01#toc6

Answer (score 1):

If you use glib `timeout_add` instead of `idle_add` the impact on CPU costs is minimal (I even didn't notice any). Here is a full example with GTK2 + gevent:

```
import gtk
import gobject

import gevent
from gevent.server import StreamServer
from gevent.socket import create_connection


def handle_tcp(socket, address):
    print 'new tcp connection!'
    while True:
        socket.send('hello\n')
        gevent.sleep(1)


def client_connect(address):
    sockfile = create_connection(address).makefile()
    while True:
        line = sockfile.readline()  # returns None on EOF
        if line is not None:
            print "<<<", line,
        else:
            break


def _trigger_loop():
    gobject.timeout_add(10, gevent_loop, priority=gobject.PRIORITY_HIGH)


def gevent_loop():
    gevent.sleep(0.001)
    _trigger_loop()
    return False


tcp_server = StreamServer(('127.0.0.1', 1234), handle_tcp)
tcp_server.start()
gevent.spawn(client_connect, ('127.0.0.1', 1234))
gevent.spawn(client_connect, ('127.0.0.1', 1234))

_trigger_loop()
gtk.main()
```